# Python mechanize or any other library to login into google to read groups

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, ssl-certificate, mechanize

I am trying to read google groups so it is expecting to login into google account.

I used Mechanize for that but I am getting SSL verification error

```
from mechanize import Browse
br=Browse()
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_refresh(False)  
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]


br.open("https groups login url") now here it hits the SSL verification error.(“SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED” Error)
```

1. is there anyway to avoid SSL verification issue?
2. is there any library that I can use?

Note: I tried with UrlLib2 I am able to set empty SSL context and able to avoid this SSL certificate issue but handling login is big issue so I am trying to use some browser behavior module.

Answer (score 0):

See ["SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error/27847883) for further explanation, but here's the quick fix:

```
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```